# Does the "close quote" go before the in-text citation?

Tags: grammaticality

Where does the close quote (") go with a in-text citation?

> “Did that really happen?...No, but it could have (p. 10).”

or

> “Did that really happen?...No, but it could have" (p. 10).

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct. The citation is always supposed to be outside the quotation marks.

The first version would make "(p.10)." a part of what that person said.

Answer (score 2):

In MLA, APA, CMS, and I don’t know how many other citational styles, the invariable rule is to put the close quotation marks *before* the parenthetical citation, but hold off on the sentence-ending period till *after* the parenthetical citation. (This last bit was not asked about, but if I had a nickel for every period I have had to mark for relocation thus in a student paper, I would be rich.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how [Diana Hacker's Research and Documentation](http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/RES5e_ch09_s1-0001.html) (Bedford St. Martin's) gives the basic format for an APA citation:

> Ordinarily, introduce the quotation with a signal phrase that includes the author’s last name followed by the year of publication in parentheses. Put the page number preceded by "p." (or "pp." for more than one page) in parentheses after the quotation.
>
> Critser (2003) noted that despite growing numbers of overweight Americans, many health care providers still “remain either in ignorance or outright denial about the health danger to the poor and the young” (p. 5).
>
> If the author is not named in the signal phrase, place the author’s name, the year, and the page number in parentheses after the quotation: (Critser, 2003, p. 5).
> NOTE: APA style requires the year of publication in an in-text citation. Do not include a month, even if the entry in the reference list includes the month.

So that means that the quotation marks go directly after the end of the quotation, where they are followed by the citation in parentheses and the ending punctuation.